# Matlab R2011b mex file compilation error "Unrecognized switch: -argcheck"

Tags: matlab, compilation, mex

When i try to compile mex files at matlab r2011b it gives an error as below.

How can i fix it?

I downloaded codes from http://www.timotheecour.com/software/ncut_multiscale/ncut_multiscale.html and compile

my system: core i7 - 64bit win7

```
You can change your home, image, and results directories if you want ; see startup/definePaths
*********************************
Error: compilation of \cimgnbmap_lower.cpp failed :     Usage:
        MEX [option1 ... optionN] sourcefile1 [... sourcefileN]
            [objectfile1 ... objectfileN] [libraryfile1 ... libraryfileN]

    Use the -help option for more information, or consult the MATLAB API Guide.


  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2011B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -argcheck.


*********************************
....... (same error for other 11 files)


There were 0 files compiled

Error: There were 12 erroneous files during compilation
\cimgnbmap_lower.cpp
\mex_XindicatorTimesX.cpp
\mex_affinity_option.cpp
\mex_computeRowSum.cpp
\mex_constraint_classes.cpp
\mex_extractMaxima.cpp
\mex_istril.cpp
\mex_neighborW.cpp
\mex_normalizeColumns.cpp
\mex_projection_QR_symmetric.cpp
\mex_w_times_x_symmetric_tril.cpp
\spmtimesd.cpp

ans = 

1x12 struct array with fields:
    isErrorDuringCompilation
    isCompilationFailed
    message
    compiledFilename
    file
    isError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

-argcheck option for mex is removed from MATLAB R2010b. Which version of MATLAB are you using? You can safely remove this option if you think your mex files do not expect to have invalid calls to API functions. For example calling mxGetPr with a NULL pointer would crash. "-argcheck" would catch this and throw as an error.

Comment: how do i remove this option?

Comment: What are you doing to compile the cpp files? You must be running a "mex" command somewhere. Remove the argument "-argcheck" to the mex command.

Comment: I'm getting a similar error when I try to install SPAI on matlab...mex:  -argcheck not a valid option. And I don't know how to disable this option.